# request data from Github api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api, octokit

I wanted to import data(get users) from https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#list-users
the code in JS file(reactjs) is like

```
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/rest");
const octokit = new Octokit();

async function myAsyncMethod() {
  const result = await octokit.request("GET /users");
  console.log(result.data);
}
myAsyncMethod();
```

but in the browser, didn't show anything, it's the correct way to get the data?

Comment: where are you adding this code?

Comment: in index.js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on where do you want to call this piece of code.

For instance, let's say that you need to call it as soon as the component that you're going to display is rendered. In that case, you will need to use the `useEffect` hook, and call your function from there.

See the following piece of code (I'm using the component `App` just for the example).

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/rest");

export default function App() {
  const octokit = new Octokit();

  useEffect(() => {
    getGithubUsers();
  });

  async function getGithubUsers() {
    const result = await octokit.request("GET /users");
    console.log(result.data);
  }

  return <></>;
}
```